# Macro to sum column with criteria stops unexpectedly

Tags: excel, vba

I want compute the sum of a column by `VBA`.
This following my code:

```
Sub CALRU()
       ECP_CA = 0
       Radome_CA = 0
            For i = 1 To 21726
                If Cells(i, "L") = "GET" Then
                    If Cells(i, "H") = "2014" Then
                        ECP_CA = ECP_CA + Cells(i, "J")
                    Else
                        MsgBox "not found"
                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox "not found"
                End If
            Next i

End Sub
```

My loop when it find the first result is true it stoped.And do not termine the rest of column.
Someone, can give me a suggestion where's the problem ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code stops, you must click the **OK** button in the MsgBox for the macro to continue.

**EDIT#1:**

This may help solve your problem:

```
Sub CALRU()
       ECP_CA = 0
       Radome_CA = 0
            For i = 1 To 21726
                If Cells(i, "L") = "GET" Then
                    If Cells(i, "H") = "2014" Then
                        ECP_CA = ECP_CA + ReturnNumber(Cells(i, "J"))
                    Else
                        MsgBox "not found"
                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox "not found"
                End If
            Next i

End Sub

Public Function ReturnNumber(v As Variant) As Double
    Dim L As Long, temp As String, CH As String
    L = Len(v)
    If L = 0 Then
        ReturnNumber = 0
    Exit Function
End If
    temp = ""
    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Or CH = "." Or CH = "-" Then temp = temp & CH
    Next i
    If temp = "" Then
        ReturnNumber = 0
    Else
        ReturnNumber = CDbl(temp)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Of course I clicked the OK, but I mean by stoped it do not termine running, it return to the code in macro and it return an error : Incompatibility of type

Comment: @vero  that error usually means some or all cells in column **J** contain *Text* values rather than *Numbers*

Comment: Yes exactly! the incompatibility is in this line: "ECP_CA = ECP_CA + Cells(i, "J")" ====>>  I added "Dim i As Double" just bellow  "Sub CALRU()"  but in vein

Comment: What @Gary is getting at is if one of your values in column J is text then you'll get a data type mismatch error - e.g.  `1+A` won't work.  The incompatibility isn't in that line - it's in the values return in `Cells(i,"J")`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook yes it's in the value return in Cells(i,"J") =10685.22 and ECP_CA = 60808, but I added  "Dim i As Double".

Comment: 10685.22 is only a single value - your code looks at each value in cells `J1:J21726`.  Are all the values in that range numbers?  Could there be text in there somewhere?  This formula would do the same as your code (without the messages though):  `=SUMIFS(J1:$J$21726,$H$1:$H$21726,2014,$L$1:$L$21726,"GET")`

Comment: @vero  See my **EDIT1**

Answer (score 0):

It should work now:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CALRU()

    Dim ecp_ca          As Double
    Dim Radome_CA       As Double
    Dim i               As Long

    ecp_ca = 0
    Radome_CA = 0

    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 1 To 217
            If .Cells(i, "L") = "GET" Then
                If .Cells(i, "H") = "2014" Then
                    ecp_ca = ecp_ca + .Cells(i, "J")
                Else
                    Debug.Print "not found"
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print "not found"
            End If
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

I have tried up to 217, because I didn't want to wait to print for 21K. I have changed the MsgBoxes to `Debug.Print` and I have added `With ActiveSheet`, as far as this can be a problem as well. `Option Explicit` is also added.

Comment: That wouldn't work if one of the values is text and variables need to be double to work with fractions of a number (10685.22)